# Increment invoice number on html form submit in WordPress

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, wordpress, forms

I have been searching for hours and I do not understand MySQL so I am wondering if it is possible to do this another way. I have a custom html payment form that submits invoice number, amount, and name to a payment processor. I want to be able to add in a transaction number that starts at 30200 and auto increments by one every time the form is submitted to the processor. I wrote a simple increment function:

```
var i = 30200;
function buttonClick() {
    document.getElementById('transNum').value = ++i;
}
```

The code passes the incremented variable correctly but doesn't store the new value anywhere and I do not know how to store it. Every time the form is submitted the transaction number gets set to 30201. Is there a way to store it in an external file and call the last number stored? Like I said I do not know MySQL so storing it in the database is beyond my understanding. There has to be an easy understandable way for me to accomplish this but I cannot find a solution.

**EDIT** ALMOST THERE (I HOPE)

After a lot of research I am trying to use mySQL to accomplish this task.

So I followed a YouTube video and used phpMyAdmin to create a table called refNum and then created the auto incrementing variable refNumber and set it to 30300.

I created a php file and uploaded it to the server called reference.php with this code inside it:

```
<?php 
function get_refNum($ref){
global $wpdb;
$results = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT refNumber FROM refNum");
return $results;
};
?>
```

Then in my form I wrote this code to call the page and get the results from the database:

```
 function getTransNumber(){
 $.ajax({
 url : '/reference.php',
 method : 'post',
 data : {$results},
 });
 $results = document.getElementById('invoiceNum').value;
 }
 window.onload = getTransNumber;
```

My problem is now I am getting an error Uncaught reference error: $results is not defined in my ajax call under data. Which means either I am not getting the data correctly in my php code or I am not passing the data. Can someone please point me in the right direction and tell me what I did wrong here?

Comment: is it going to increase on user basis or is it going to increase on server side for all users? solution is different for each of two situations

Comment: You should create an auto number column in mysql table for this.

Comment: The increase needs to happen every time someone submits a payment. So the first number should be 30201 and the next payment should be 30202 and so on. I understand I should use mysql table but I have no idea how and I have been trying to teach myself but I am completely confused and I cannot find a simple do this type of scenario that explains what I need to do to create a table in mysql.

Comment: When you submit a payment, you should add the invoice number in the server side of things (php). You should probably be storing all the the invoice information in the database anyways. When you hit "submit" what happens to it? Where does it go?

Comment: The form literally only collects the invoice number and the payment amount and then you click the pay now button and it sends you to FirstData to actually process the payment so I only want to send 3 pieces of info to them. The transaction number is for my records to update when someone pays because sometimes it takes months for someone to pay an invoice and it is easier to reconcile by transaction numbers.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a global number, that needs to be increased for anyone accessing the page (and not forgotten when the page is closed), then you need some place to store the last used number.

Whether or not you understand MySQL, the normal solution for this is to use *some kind* of database, although that doesn't need to be MySQL.

Comment: This is why I asked if there is another way to accomplish this as I do not understand mysql. If mysql is the way then I do not even know where to begin. i have been trying to research this but I cannot find a way to get the number to start at 30200 instead of 1?

Comment: @DragonetDesign well, when I started programming PHP in 2003 I also had to learn it. It wasn't super easy, but it didn't take me more than a few days to figure out the basics. I would suggest you just try to tackle problems 1 at a time, and if you get stuck... ask specific questions. They are usually easy to answer. How do a make my field not start at 1, is definitely something a lot of people can help with.

Comment: Nobody understands MySQL until they take the time to.

Comment: @DragonetDesign it's a bit rude of a response. The issue remains that you need some kind of persistent state, and the standard route for that is some database. I guess you're assuming that I'm not trying to give you the best possible answer, and I'm deliberately giving you an answer you don't wish to hear; but I'm here taking the time to answer your question.

Comment: Even if it's not the ideal answer for you, perhaps you can try to at least be polite about it. In your metaphor: Lets say your quiz requires working calculus knowledge, are you going to be mad at the people that tell you there might not be a shortcut?

Comment: I appreciate trying to offer help and what I need is someone to say hey look here because this will help you. The problem I am having is after searching for now days I cannot find a solution and I am no closer to one than when I started. I cannot even find a online tutorial that shows me the basics of mysql. So I apologize if my response was rude but telling me you had to learn mysql when you started programming doesn't help me find where I go to do that. Every tutorial I have found assumes I already know the basics and I don't so they are just confusing me more.

Comment: Makes sense, I just included that bit about my own history, because I thought maybe MySQL just seemed too daunting right now, and I thought it would lessen that a bit... I wasn't trying to throw it in your face. One of the things that I didn't realize before, is: Do you have a node.js server? Because the first prerequisite to being able to store data permanently is you need a server-side language to handle this.

Comment: Ok so first off thank you because you got me to think about what I was searching for in a different way. I am using WordPress for my site so this is not a normal situation. I was able to find a video to create the table and value in phpMyAdmin and I updated my question above. The only catch is after all my research I have no idea if what I am doing is correct.

Comment: I see; wordpress development can be a bit tricky and will unfortunately mean you will have to add PHP + wordpress to the list you need to pick up. It's a bit too much for me to walk you through it, but I hope you figure it all out

Comment: You have been incredibly helpful and I hope what I am doing is on the right track. Would you mind looking at my edit and let me know if I am close and maybe where my mistake is?

Comment: @DragonetDesign, you are doing amazing. I think the query should probably be `SELECT refNumber FROM refNum` . Unfortunately i can't help you with your problem because I have very little wordpress experience

Answer (score 0):

I'm not a big MySQL user but there is an AutoIncrement attribute that each column can have (or not).

Here is an example from https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_autoincrement.asp

CREATE TABLE Persons (
Personid int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
LastName varchar(255) NOT NULL,
FirstName varchar(255),
Age int,
PRIMARY KEY (Personid)
);

That first field doesn't need to be provided by you when inserting. It will do it for you everytime you create a record. Not totally sure how to set the first one to 32000 though.

Comment: SQL - ALTER TABLE <table> AUTO_INCREMENT=32000; looks like it would work for setting the first index and then counting up from there.

Comment: Where do I place this code? I apologize for the ignorance but I do not know mysql and I am trying to find a tutorial but I cannot seem to find a beginners tutorial. Everything I find already assumes you know where and how to implement this code.

Comment: Hi, that is added in the database table definition itself. Hopefully your install comes with something like phpAdmin. That will show you all the options you can choose from. It will also let you paste that code into a SQL window to alter a table manually. There is plenty of info on youtube for that sort of operation. I'm sure you can find an MySQL course online.